# "Horrible Question" vs. "Perfect for SO Archives"

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed
>   answers to every question about programming.

What kind of questions fit into this library? A lazy question about the best way to determine whether a point is inside a polygon, or a detailed, rigorous question about a segfault in a particle system used for a pinball game in which the author posts an MCVE along with detailed notes of what he tried to do to fix it which simply boils down to a typo in a line of code?

**Proposal:**

Include in the help documentation some kind of distinction that helps distinguish questions like these:

[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (likely to be considered opinion-based today)

[How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test) (likely to be considered lazy, too broad, opinion-based)

[Performance optimization strategies of last resort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort) (actually closed years later as too broad)

[Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) (likely to be considered opinion-based)

... from *actually* bad questions for the site. These are some of the best kinds of questions for the site as an archive that helps prevent redundant questions many people might otherwise repeatedly want to ask.

**A Great Question**

A great question, if we're talking about archival purposes to answer questions that repeatedly crop up, tends to have the characteristics that can often be interpreted by many as "too broad", "opinion-based", and often "lazy".

These are the types of questions that tend to show up when programmers search Google for something and find SO to actually provide one of best resources. There's a common characteristic typically found there: the best kind of archived questions are very general (and therefore somewhat "broad"), loosely-detailed (and therefore somewhat "lazy"), possibly opinion-based (seeking best practices from experts), and have extremely detailed answers where people are competing to provide the best one.

Yet we have this awkward dilemma. Given the kind of questions the site encourages recently (or at least based on how the community interprets it), these types of questions have a tendency to get down-voted if not outright closed. I've seen my share get down-voted and closed this way while I kept thinking to myself, *"If only someone like `Mystical` answers this question, it could become the next great entry to the site"*. Instead it gets shut down before even having such an opportunity. As a result, such potential gem-producing questions often don't get much attention, and therefore lose their chance to become the next great entry to the SO archive.

**Horrible Questions**

Nevertheless, there are other types of "too broad" (can't answer without writing a book), "opinion-based" (can't possibly hope to get an expert consensus), and "lazy" (seeking other people to solve a narrowly-defined problem the author is having with minimal effort on the part of the author). These are horrible for the site.

**Distinction**

I'm not sure exactly how to draw the distinction between these two. English is not my first language, and I would leave the details to those in control of the text in the help center, the close options, etc. All I know is that there *is* a distinction, albeit murky.

**Archival Qualities of SO**

SO has become a great archive for expert knowledge. Sometimes I've found SO to be one of the best resources when seeking programming-related information, occasionally even more helpful than a Siggraph paper (I work in graphics). Where it can be excellent is that the best answers often come from those entrenched in the code: seasoned veterans who have tackled the same challenges.

Yet it really seems like this quality of SO is diminishing. What it is now encouraging (either directly or through the community's interpretation of what constitutes a good question) seems to be questions that are in the "technical support" vein. The site encourages detailed questions that are often very narrowly-applicable to only the very exact problem the author is working on.

While this is great for helping the author, these questions aren't necessarily the ones that are greatest for the site. The best ones for the site often boil down to the lazy, general, opinion-based, "What is the best way to do [X]?" kind of question.

So my request is to try to find a way in the wording and the help to establish a distinction that no longer discourages these questions which have so much potential to add to the site.

**Edit**

I realize I could be subject to great deal of bias here from selection bias to nostalgia glasses. This proposal is admittedly better suited to be taken into consideration by those with broader statistics. The one thing that doesn't seem to be prone to a misinterpretation of the past is simply what constitutes a great entry to the SO archives. A detailed question tends to be, by definition, narrowly applicable, since each detail that narrowly defines the problem tends to isolate its relevance to a smaller and smaller group. I am not exactly sure if "broad", "lazy", and "opinion-based" must go hand-in-hand with the opposite of such qualities, yet we're unlikely to find answers to questions already asked if the predominant questions are very narrowly-suited for the one asking the question.

Comment: Keep in mind there's selection bias here: old, maybe-no-longer-allowed questions that didn't receive great answers have probably already been deleted.

Comment: That I realize -- though I've been a member of this site for far longer than this account (my former was tied to my former workplace, and I inadvertently retired it). But I also realize I could just be looking at things through hazy nostalgia glasses. I remember seeing my share of homework questions and all that over half a decade ago. Yet something was different -- maybe just due to the lower volume. My thoughts on what leaves behind these archives could have completely missed -- it is certainly possible.

Comment: Yet what constitutes a most useful archival question should typically fit some of those characteristics -- a loosely detailed question (because details reduce "generality", where I'm using "generality" in the sense of how many other people are going to find it interesting/useful -- "applicability" -- more detailed questions narrow it) combined with extremely detailed answers.

Answer (score 4):

Slow down there. Only *half* of these questions would be ones I'd personally consider topical and exemplary for the site.  The other two ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)) are asking for the best opinion, and lead us down a path of wide and broad discussion as opposed to a concrete, simple-to-digest answer.

You've also fallen (perhaps knowingly?) into the trap of older questions.  Older questions generally had this style because what was acceptable on the site wasn't as well defined as it is today.  I won't deny that some of these questions are valuable, but that value should be interpreted on a case-by-case basis.  There's no way to create an algorithm* explicitly to ensure that users know the difference between those questions.

The only real way we'd have to educate the user is through comments, discussions like this on Meta, and the smattering of commentators who won't hesitate to downvote a question to oblivion should it try to replicate this pattern again.  The latter I wish didn't have to happen since it does discourage participation, but it does, and it is a decent teaching method.

These sorts of questions are snowflakes.  They should be regarded as such and never really generalized, especially since their topicality is subjective as I've demonstrated.

Comment: Liked even though you disagree! They are certainly subjective, but that second one (point in polygon test) actually helped me better understand the logic behind code I was using for years. It was one of the answers that really drew me to the site (along with pretty much anything `Mystical` participated in). The question was rather subjective but the answers not so much. I might be focusing on the wrong problem -- perhaps it's merely the incoming traffic now that's making it difficult to leave such snowflakes behind. I don't know -- all I can see is the trend where...

Comment: ... all the useful answers to me personally, and that I see linked often, tend to fit in this category (loosely-detailed question, highly-detailed answers). I realize I could also simply be looking at things in hindsight -- a few years might prove me wrong and we might see snowflakes from 2015. But it doesn't feel that way -- and that's mainly my worry.

Comment: The other worry is that, admittedly this is far from a daily occurrence, but I have seen those "potential snowflakes" melt to the ground -- the loosest, subjective kind of `"what is the best way to do [...]"` question (not duplicated to my knowledge), shining with potential (if only people competed for the answer), quickly retired. Perhaps they simply don't fit anymore -- but I'm worried that through their dismissal, we might likewise be losing the chance for new snowflakes.

Comment: Apologies for verbose comments (I'm verbose), but this idea of "subjective" and "general" are not necessarily mutually exclusive as I see it. I'm defining "general" in this context as `"having interest to a wider range of people"`. Take the Q about casts w/`malloc`. In my former team, we had a standard that *required* us to cast. To argue otherwise would be shot down as opinion. Yet the answer is very useful to all C programmers -- it gave me the rationale not to do it. But it's never quite divorced from bias -- it would be difficult for us to say that not doing so would *only* be pros.