# Very Broad Question, Very Nice Answer

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I want to direct attention to this thread which got shut down for asking a question that was too broad. Please see the answer from Aidan at the bottom.

[How can a 3D game render an object without having a sprite for every single angle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880396/how-are-3d-models-rendered-in-a-game)

The answer has 6 up-votes and was already provided 4 hours before the thread was closed as being too broad.

I have a lot of thoughts on this phenomena where a question that would normally seem bad because it's very general and not asking a very narrowly-defined problem gets shut down. This is a related thought: ["Horrible Question" vs. "Perfect for SO Archives"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310875/horrible-question-vs-perfect-for-so-archives)

To me it's a tragedy to see a Q&A with that much potential get shut down, so I voted to reopen it.

Now Aidan's answer isn't perfect by any means. He glosses over the subjects, doesn't bother to explain the difference between scanline rasterization and raytracing (something I requested him to add), etc. But it's an answer with a lot of effort put into it, had potential to become even better (if the motivation wasn't lost due to the question being shut down), could have invited even better answers, and precisely the kind of answer other entry-level users who wondered about the same kind of thing might want.

If the site really cares about posterity, links like these to broad questions tend to hit a lot more people wanting to ask the same question than even the most meticulously-detailed troubleshooting question about some very specific piece of code, or worse, a homework question answered by the Fastest Gun in the West which points out a typo.

I really think we should think twice about what we consider "too broad". There are definitely some questions that are "too vague", but there's another category that can really produce some of the most generally-applicable answers (as in hitting the widest audience looking for already-answered questions) because the questions are very general.

Here's another one: [How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)

Questions like these shouldn't be cast into the void if they end up resulting in a really great answer that could be of interest to many people in the future. In trying to enforce the rules so strongly, I think we forget the whole point of moderation -- to make sure the site leaves behind useful information to be found later. Shutting down these questions, and especially after they receive such a detailed answer that's being well-received, kind of defeats that whole purpose.

So I don't know, what do you guys think? Aren't these kinds of questions good for the site when they receive a detailed answer? Should we have a better distinction about what is "too broad"?

Comment: Can a good answer make a mediocre question worthwhile? [Yes.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)

Comment: Absolutely -- but here's another way I see it. Can a good question always receive a good answer?

Comment: No, hence [the blog post I linked to](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) - questions are just sand, even the best question is no guarantee of a useful answer.

Comment: That's a very nice link! But I guess I'm worried that sometimes the best way to make a pearl is only with sand. For example, if you have a peek at any of my questions, I would say that they're not pearl-producers. I think they're reasonable questions -- the kind encouraged by the site (except for the one where I was asking about code generators). But they're not so widely applicable because I made the questions very specific to my needs. Meanwhile these two sloppy questions I linked are pearl mines. One of those even sets up a stage for competition, asking for a best answer.

Comment: So, there's a lot of sand that probably won't produce pearls at all, or will produce very small pearls that grow at a very slow rate. Sand is common; pearls are rare. The pearl depends on the oyster, not the sand - cramming ever-bigger grains of sand into oysters isn't gonna guarantee better pearls.

Comment: I got a little lost in the sand/pearl metaphor -- but the way I look at it is like, if we want a pearl.. I know a question I can ask -- it'd be a horrible, broad, opinion-based one like "What's the most efficient technique for ray/triangle intersection?" <-- horrible, opinionated, overly broad question.. but it could very easily produce a magnificent pearl (provided it doesn't get shut down, which it probably will). I'm seeing it like the finest pearls need those kinds of questions. It'd be the kind of question I'd never ask personally (mine tend to be very specific), but ripe with potential.

Comment: I want to suggest a different quality metric (just for discussion)... that is, to judge a question based on its *"likelihood of producing a really great answer that would interest people in the future"*. In that sense, even the laziest kind of, *"What is the best way to do [...]"* might actually be the *highest-quality* question even though they would be considered low enough to shut down ATM. These are exactly the kinds of questions that are anti-FGITW and reward the very best answers, get people to compete on trying to outdo each other's answers on a quality level and not just speed level.

Comment: The potential there lies in the existence of someone who can riff on that idea and produce a really great treatment of the subject. Of course, if such a person is around, they can do the same with a rather more specific question - for instance, one based on an unsuccessful attempt to produce an efficient intersection test. The only real difference between these two potential questions is that the latter *requires* at least a serviceable answer, while the former could well end in guesses and google results with nothing of value produced at all.

Comment: I agree mostly except for the "only real difference" part. A Q formed in the context of a specific intersection test may be titled in a way such that it is overlooked by many. The specificity of the question might also narrow the generality of the answer. While I agree that the latter context would provide a stronger form of quality control on the answer (since the person raising the question will be verifying the solutions himself), it also could have a tendency to reduce the generality of the entire page and make it mostly serve only the interest of the one immediately seeking a solution.

Comment: There's a danger, it's true, that an *extremely* specific title will discourage people from answering, even when they might otherwise be inclined to do so. This isn't always a bad thing, but it is worth taking into account - as well as the reverse, which is that a very *general* title may drive away potential answerers as well. Best to aim for a title (and question!) that describes the problem with as much specificity as is needed for the answer, but no more.

Comment: I guess also the way I'm looking at it is that our personal queries often aren't so sophisticated -- at least mine aren't. I look for things like, `"efficient ray AABB intersection"`, not `"How Can We Optimize This Ray/AABB Slab Implementation Using SSE 4?"` So I often think the qualities that make a question "great" (in the sense I'm describing it, not by SO's current metrics) require a fairly broad question lacking many details. In any case, apologies for using up your time!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Fishing with a bucket

A trap that many askers have fallen into over the years comes from thinking that *breadth* will produce better results. It's easy to find seemingly-broad questions that attracted *great* answers without seeing the thousands of them that attracted bad answers or no answers at all; whether browsing through old questions or just observing the results of a Google search, you could be forgiven for thinking that the best way to get a good answer is to cast a wide net: ask for *everything* and take what you find useful.

In practice, this is horribly inefficient. You might get lucky; you might win the lottery and attract the most amazing article written just for you by some passing expert on the topic... You might also get a nice trout dinner by standing outside with a bucket waiting for fish to fall from the sky.

If someone wants to write a lengthy article on a subject, they'll find a way to do that; the question is just their launchpad. Plenty of excellent answers have been written for very specific questions; indeed, it's perfectly ok to [make questions more general](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) if they manage to attract answers that can be useful in broader situations.

### The wrong sort of sand

Which just leaves us with the question of what to do with broad questions that *did* manage to attract one or more amazingly-useful answers. Well... why do anything? As I've said before, [the only good questions are the ones that get good answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306368/should-a-howto-question-about-launching-c-threads-be-closed-for-lacking-an-mcv/306373#306373):

> You don't throw away a pearl because you don't believe the oyster
> should've been able to produce it. As much as it chafes to admit it,
> answers *are* a factor when determining the worth of a question -
> indeed, they are probably the most important factor. All of our rules,
> policies, guidelines and so on are built around two fundamental goals:
>
> 1. Encouraging useful answers
> 2. Helping others with the same question find those answers
>
> The most carefully-constructed question on earth is worthless if it
> doesn't achieve #1 and ideally #2 as well. When asking yourself
> whether or not to close a question, **first and foremost ask if it
> will be usefully answered.** If it is, might be, or you really don't
> know... Then don't worry about it.

If you find a broad question with an answer you find useful, and notice that it's *already* been closed... Then **edit it**. Focus it as best you can; make it fit the answers that are useful to yourself and others. Then go earn [the privilege to vote to reopen](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: I imagine there must be an epic amount of volume I'm overlooking that you can see. Nevertheless, I'm still stuck on the point that #2 would require a pretty general (and therefore rather broad) question. In general I think the best type of questions for #2 have a strong "quality" factor associated with the answers and don't boil down to black and white correct vs. incorrect (those reward the fastest answer that gets it right instead of the highest-quality answer). About the suggestion to edit, I don't really see what to edit to make the answer help #2. It seems best for #2 to keep it broad.

Comment: Though I noticed your edit and that really makes the question better (great example for me to look at). I wonder if that would qualify as no longer "too broad" (your edit kind of seems to make it even broader and detached from specifics), but it definitely became far more valuable and really aids #2!

Comment: Then again, on the flip side, there are "too broad" questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908291/how-do-i-go-about-building-a-gui-compiler#33908291 ... probably hopeless to produce any kind of reasonable answer. I find it difficult to distinguish the two perfectly without thinking so much about what kind of answers they might produce. To me the closest way I can distinguish them so far is "too vague". The hopeless ones tend to be "too vague".

Comment: @Ike It takes a bit of domain knowledge in many cases to be able to see the difference. In your example, i have no idea what it takes to "build a GUI" compiler, so I can't possibly decide whether or not it would be able to produce a useful answer. On the flip side, if someone asked "How do I implement a `noConflict` method into my javascript library similar to how jQuery does it" I would leave it alone (or possibly even answer it) because I know that it would be a relatively short and to the point answer that could be useful to future developers for multiple reasons. (unless it's a dupe.)

Comment: @KevinB That's very true. I tend to skip those if they're really outside my domain. I'm really having a hard time drawing a distinction. Code generation and building GUIs based on reflection and so forth tends to be somewhat close to my domain, and there's something I could tell about this one that seems pretty hopeless to produce any reasonable answer, if only for the vagueness of the question. "What's everyone's fastest way to do a ray/triangle intersection?" is something that doesn't even take much domain-specific knowledge to deduce that it could provide a competitive ground...

Comment: @KevinB ... for answers that could start competing with each other, where experts start correcting each other's little inaccuracies and start discussing details at an expert level about their answers. That, to me, is the magical SO moment when the votes are really being used as quality control over the answers... and I want to see more of those magical moments. But I don't know exactly how to define what sets up that kind of stage where such magic happens -- it is easy to see the opposite one with troubleshooting questions where the first answer that gets it right becomes the quality metric.

Comment: @KevinB Mainly I just want to see more of those moments where I'm dazzled by the expertise (or even merely the effort as in the linked case) of those competing to provide the best answer. That's one of the most unique qualities I see that SO has going for it, when that magic happens. I don't know precisely what leads to those magical moments -- only that the precise opposite seems to be a question so narrowly applicable to only the person asking the question.

Comment: I always downvote "What is the fastest" and "What is the best" or "most elegant" because those are are all completely baseless, unless the question specifies what exactly is being measured and what conditions would make one "better" than the other, or if that part can be edited out without affecting the question too much.. I don't see such questions as being that useful. "Best" "Most Useful" "Most Elegant" and "Fastest" are all great buzzwords for marketing, but don't really translate that well to programing.

Comment: @KevinB It's an awkward territory -- there are those smelly ones like, "is a for loop or while loop" faster, and then there's those interesting ones like that point-in-polygon one where we got people competing on the best answer. I think in a better world there would be far better ways to kind of lead to the same answers without asking such an obnoxious question using those kinds of buzzwords, to be a little more objective about it. But I'm drawing blanks often -- a lot more of those examples where the magic happens to me have that kind of subjectivity to them.

Comment: @KevinB Where I'm drawn  to those "best/fastest/most useful/elegant" kind of topics is that they do establish a setting quickly where the answer can't easily be voted merely based on correctness/incorrectness (those types reward the FGITW). "Do I cast the result of malloc?" is an ambiguous question, yet it is the top-voted question in the [c] tag. And the answers basically boil down to best practices, which are never devoid of bias, but don't have to be devoid of solid rationale.

Comment: Exactly, there's going to be edge cases that can... skirt around the general rule and be "on topic", subjectivity is allowed, to an extent. but it's usually difficult to craft a question that is asking for something that is subjective that will remain open. In some sub communities such questions will immediately be shot down (javascript), while in others they seem to be more welcome.

Comment: @KevinB Agreed -- I'm afraid I don't have any confidence whatsoever about how exactly to deduce the distinction within those gray zones where a seemingly horrible question can lead to the greatest answers. :-( All that seems clear to me is that they exist, and that these murky areas sometimes set the stage for the most competitive answers. What I'm worried about -- maybe it's too strong of an opinion, but I think the grey zones are actually the greatest source of the best answers.

Comment: How do we open chat, i'm sure we're bugging shog at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I want to offer a somewhat contradictory answer to my own question. I realized something after discussing this subject with various people.

My woes related to the site have to do with how many basic questions there are for which there is typically only one terse, correct answer to provide. `"This question is coming from someone who  doesn't know how to use pointers... NEXT! This next question is the same basic thing.. NEXT! This person doesn't know how to use a debugger and wants us to spot the faulty line of code for him... NEXT!"`

They might have an MCVE, but they yield little challenge for the seasoned veteran. In those cases, if some really high-rep user pitches in, you end up seeing like a Linux kernel maintainer answer the most basic question about how pointers work competing to be the fastest gun in the west.

***It's sad.***

It seems inevitable that experts are a small minority. On top of that, experts ask questions far less frequently. They're typically far more self-sufficient, know how to search for the right things themselves, and have a lot more answers than questions (opposite of the beginner).

Yet I realized today that in the rare case that an expert asks a question, it could be very narrow, not broad at all, extremely specific and still of tremendous educational value provided it receives any answers. Esoteric gold can be found in those cases regardless of the characteristics of the question beyond the fact that it was very advanced.

The reason I think I'm hung up on broad and opionated grey-zone questions is that this is the one type of question that might really and deeply challenge an expert even if the question is posed by a total novice who doesn't know what he's doing. It seems like one of the few cases where we can expect to see tremendous variety in the answers: their quality, their level of detail, the scope they tackle. In those cases, we don't see 10 boring but correct answers which are almost identical.

That's why I like some of these broad questions and sometimes see them as the oasis in a desert of basic questions which can only prompt a basic answer. But it's for a very different reason than I initially thought.